# CoreNet60 Angular always returning 404 error

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, webapi

i am porting over an applciation written in netcore2 to 6 with angular 13. When running in visual studio i always get a 404 error for every web api controller / method

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class GetOptionsController : Controller
{
    private readonly GetOptionsService _getOptionsService;

    public GetOptionsController(GetOptionsService getOptionsService)
    {
        _getOptionsService = getOptionsService; 
    }

    [HttpGet]  
    public IActionResult GetOptions()
    {            
        var options = _getOptionsService.GetOptions();
        return  Ok(options);            
    }

}
}


    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; 
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';  
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs'; 
    import { IOption } from '../interfaces/option';

 
  
@Injectable()
export class OptionsService {
   
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  
    getOptions(): Observable<IOption[]> {
      return this.http.get<IOption[]>("getoptions", { responseType: 'json' }); 
    }  
}
```

when creating the project i chose ASP.NET Core With Angular (maybe this wasnt the best choice?) and just added new api methods and angular components.  all web apis return 404 (breakpoints in the controller are never hit) except WeatherForecastController that is created by default when the project is created.  i dont see it doing anything different than im doing. this worked in the old project (core 2.0 with angular 6).   POST methods dont work either.

i have been trying to figure this out for days and cant.  can anyone help?

Comment: Can you make the request using postman/swagger/insomnia etc?

Comment: i get the same 404 response in postman.   when i deploy to iis however, i get a 200 status (i see this in chrome network tab)

Comment: Hi @Dexter Morgan, I suggest you can run your application on Kestrel and check the output panel to see the port number. .Net 6 split the backend and frontend port number.

Answer (score 5):

Did you get it fixed?

I met same problem and was stuck for a while, finally I found it's because the Angular proxy need be updated.

Try add your Api in proxy.conf.js files, it works for me:

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: [
      // ...
      "/getoptions"
    ],
    // ...
  }
]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75505538/angular-asp-net-core-web-api-404-on-new-controller-endpoints/75505643?noredirect=1#comment133218444_75505643 

Still unable to get the angular app to hit the new endpoint, did you do anything else besides adding additional endpoints to the context ?

Answer (score 0):

it is not a good idea to use  only controller name as a route. But if you still want it, try to use action routing

```
[Route("~/GetOptions")]  
public IActionResult GetOptions()
```

Comment: thank you very much for your response this did not seem to work 

Request URL: http://localhost:44481/getoptions
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:44481
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin



i added this to my api controll
 [HttpGet]
 [Route("~/GetOptions")]
 public IActionResult GetOptions()