# Angular + ASP.NET Core Web API : 404 on new controller endpoints

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an Angular standalone project which has an ASP.NET Core Web API added to it. I followed this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-angular?view=vs-2022).

When placing a breakpoint in the weatherforecast controller, it's hit with no issues. When I create a new controller called `Account` with an endpoint called `Login` - like this:

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class AccountController : ControllerBase
    {
        private ILogger<AccountController> _logger;
        private IAccountService _accountService;
        
        public AccountController(ILogger<AccountController> logger, IAccountService accountService)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _accountService = accountService;
        }

        [HttpPost(Name = "login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel model)
        {
            var response = await _accountService.Login(model);
           
            return Ok(response);
        }
    }
```

and it's called via the Angular project, I get 404 not found:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AccountService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  login(credentials: Credential) {
    this.http.post<AuthResponse>('/account/login', credentials).subscribe({
      next: (n) => console.log(n),
      error: (e) => console.error(e),
      complete: () => console.info('complete') 
  })
  }
}
```

I've also tried just `/account` yet the outcome is still the same.

I've also introduced a new endpoint which is a GET request, and that also throws a 404. Can someone spot what I'm actually doing wrong here?

*Update*

Seems this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72681036/corenet60-angular-always-returning-404-error) was experiencing the same issue as me, so I added the new endpoint to proxy.config.js, my config now looks like this:

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = [
  {
    context: [
      "/weatherforecast",
      "/Account/Login"
    ],
    target: "https://localhost:7276",
    secure: false
  }
];

module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

I've updated the angular service call to now be Account/Login :

```
login(credentials: Credential) {
    this.http.post<AuthResponse>('/Account/Login', credentials).subscribe({
      next: (n) => console.log(n),
      error: (e) => console.error(e),
      complete: () => console.info('complete') 
  })
  }
```

and the API:

```
[ApiController]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class AccountController : ControllerBase
    {
        private ILogger<AccountController> _logger;
        private readonly IAccountService _accountService;


        public AccountController(ILogger<AccountController> logger, IAccountService accountService)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _accountService = accountService;

        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("Login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel model)
        {

            var response = await _accountService.Login(model);

            return Ok(response);
        }

    }
```

Yet I still get a 404!

Comment: If you already added the Swagger, try from the swagger before calling from Angular code. Also, try decorating the controller `[AllowAnonymous]` as this end point is called without the Authorization headers.

Comment: tried that, I still get the same error though.

Comment: Anyone able to help with this? I'm still unable to get this to work

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to set the action route in the login controller.
To reach your endpoint, simply add Route.

```
       [Route("login")]
       [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel model)
        {
            var response = await _accountService.Login(model);
           
            return Ok(response);
        }
```

Comment: I've tried that, still get the same error.

Comment: @Code Ratchet This, and you may have to use `"/Account/login"` (capital A) in angular

Comment: @CodeRatchet try to make endpoint as per @Pieterjan suggestion `"/Account/login"`

Comment: using what has been shown here gives me the following error: 
Ambiguous HTTP method for action - AccountController.Login. Actions require an explicit HttpMethod binding for Swagger/OpenAPI 3.0

Comment: removing the name from HttpPost and the error goes away, yet still get 404

Comment: @CodeRatchet Just add `[HttpPost]` instead of `[HttpPost(Name = "login")].`

Comment: @KiranJoshi done, also added /Account/login to angular app, yet I get: 

Request Method: POST
Status Code: 404 Not Found

Comment: I can successfully hit this endpoint via swagger, just not via the Angular App

Comment: @CodeRatchet: See how swagger invokes the /account/login via dev tools and compare it to how angular makes a call to see the difference. How does `/account/login` in angular app map to your controller which could be running on different port unless both angular app and mvc app are running under same webserver.

Comment: @CodeRatchet  I think you forgot to add your API endpoint URL. Its is something like `'localhost:portnumber/account/login'`. Your port number you can see while you run API project just add that too

Comment: If you look at the example tutorial I followed, they don't hardcode the localhost nor port number.  Like I mentioned in the question, this setup works perfectly fine with WeatherForecast example they provide, yet when I add a new controller with a new endpoint it throws the 404

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the 404 problem you mentioned. After adding the `"/Account/Login"` path to the `proxy.conf.js` file, it is still 404.

But when I closed the Angular project, then deleted the `options` under `serve` in the `angular.json` file and added it again, and then restarted the project, it worked!

Delete this line then re-add and save:

```
"options": {
    "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.js"
}
```

Not sure what's the reason, maybe `serve.options` doesn't automatically read the updated `proxy.conf.js`? Hope this can help you.